# Chat application issue while using long polling

Tags: web-applications, chat, long-integer, polling

Sup Dev´s.

I´m currently working on a chat application like facebook but using long polling. Everytime i open a chat window a long polling request will be sent to the server and restarts if the request times out or successfully responds. But if i close the window tab for a specific friend and open the window tab again two long polling requests are waiting for a new message on the server and responds both if there is one. so it returns 2 messages for each message send from the opponent and 2 messages will be displayed. what can i do so there wont be any more long polling requests for each friends chat window? Can i bind a function to interrupt the first long polling request with the chat windows close button? Any other ways to get my thing done?

Thanks Chzn.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but binding some id to a message would prevent displaying the same message, as you will check if the message with that id already exists

Comment: Big thanks. i will try it out. If someone got another idea. I would appreciate  a reply .

Answer (score 1):

works perfectly. using this...

`if(!$("#"+result.chatid).length) {
    //do things
}`

...to check for existing messages.